# Running gmailr in shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, gmailr

I just deployed a shiny app in shinyapps.io.

It worked fine locally but when I deployed it, the gmailr authentication popup did not appear.

I checked the logs in shinyapps.io, and it is working in the background but not in the front end.

For example, when I run the function:

```
options(httr_oauth_cache=T)
gmailr::clear_token()
gmailr::gmail_auth()
```

The logs in shinyapps.io shows this which is expected, but no popup:

[image]

The expected output should be a popup asking me to choose which gmail account to authenticate.

Anyone have any experience using the gmailr package in shiny?

EDIT:

There is a file called .httr-oauth in my directory, but not rsconnect.

[image]

Should I copy this file to my rsconnect folder?

This is the directory to my app in shinyapps.io through rconnect:

[image]

Comment: Can you check/add the `.httr-oauth` file into the R session directory https://github.com/jimhester/gmailr/issues/68

Comment: @PorkChop I edited the question to include more info into what I already have. Is this what you are referring to? This is already been included in my code and still no luck. Please let me know if you are referring to something else. Thanks!

Comment: no, there should a be a file with such name in the folder directory of the shiny app

Comment: Can you provide an example of what this would look like, alittle confused

Comment: Go to your folder of the shiny app, you should see `server.R`, `ui.R`, is there a file called `.httr-oauth` where those two are?

Comment: yes there is already

Comment: edited the question, to include your comment

Comment: posted an answer @PorkChop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figure it out if anyone wants to reference this in the future:

Steps to host Gmailr in Shiny Apps:

1) set your options locally to be:

`options(httr_oob_default = TRUE, httr_oauth_cache=TRUE)`

`gmailr::clear_token()`

Run your Shiny App.

2) A popup will appear for you to select your gmail account.

3) Instead of automatically connecting you, an authentication code will appear. You need to copy and paste that authentication code in your r console where it prompts you to paste it.

4) In your work directory, you will now have a httr oauth file saved. That is what grants you access to your gmail account.

5) Exit the shiny app.
Remove the options from the script and save:

`options(httr_oob_default = TRUE, httr_oauth_cache=TRUE)`

`gmailr::clear_token()`

6) Upload the shiny app with the httr oauth file in your directoy to shinyapps.io

App should call your gmail account now without asking you to authenticate!

Comment: Finally it worked!!!! Thanks a lot! With the new version, the function is called gmailr::gm_deauth()

Comment: Now the Oauth process seems to have changed. If above does not work, which I sadly think it won't, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60507013/gmailr-without-selecting-a-pre-authorised-account-in-r/62651398#62651398)